# Codeigniter object not found 404 EasyPHP

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, pagination, easyphp

I have encountered an issue with page linking using codeigniter, when navigating from my Home screen to another screen called Live I am getting the the error below:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> 127.0.0.1 Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.4.24

The home screen link: http://127.0.0.1/projects/**companyname**/index.php/home

The link of the screen i'm trying to get to: http://127.0.0.1/projects/**companyname**/home/v_Live

home.php controller (bottom section):

```
class Home extends CI_Controller

{

public function __construct()

{

parent::__construct();

$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->model('m_login');

}

public function index()

{

if($this->session->userdata('isLogin') == FALSE)

{

redirect('login/login_form');

}else

{

$this->load->model('m_login');
$user = $this->session->userdata('username');
$data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level');
$data['user'] = $this->m_login->userData($user);
$this->load->view('home', $data);

}

--> function index () 

{ 


 function home (){
    $this->load->view("home");
    $this->load->view("v_Live");   
}

 function Live (){
    $this->load->view("home");
    $this->load->view("v_Live");    <----  
}    

}

}

}
?>
```

home view:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="Cloud_Clients.html">Cloud Clients<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/v_Live">Live</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PreProduction.html">Pre-Production</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Clients.html">Client Versions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

v_Live screen view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Live</title>
</head>

<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="Cloud_Clients.html">Cloud Clients<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>>home/v_Live">Live</a></li>
                    <li><a href="PreProduction.html">Pre-Production</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Clients.html">Client Versions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>    

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>App Server</th>
        <th>Instance Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($records as $row):
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row->id?></td>
        <td><?=$row->Client Name?></td>
        <td><?=$row->App Server?></td>
        <td><?=$row->Instance Name?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/projects/**companyname**/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

hopefully this is enough information for help.

Thanks

Comment: where is the `index.php` in second url??

Comment: It doesn't appear with is weird, I think that might be part of the problem but don't know why it's not there.

Comment: Check the answer. Add `.htaccess` file. It will solve it.

Comment: if your controller file name Home.php with first letter upper case if not should be with codeigniter 3 Here are some more htaccess for codeigniter https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the version of your codeigniter is 3, then file name should start with capital letter.

Next, have you added `.htaccess` file ?? if not access the url with index.php.
or use following code to remove the index.php from url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

add this file in root with name `.htaccess`.This will help you in removing `index.php` in url

And remove `index.php` in `$config` and make `$config['index_page'] = "";`

And also remove the `base_url()`. Codeigniter is brave enough to identify it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, last time I used codeigniter it was version 3, which could be the issue.

Comment: Just check all points, update them in your code. I will work fine.

Comment: I removed the index.php and upgraded the .htaccess file with the code that you provided but still getting the object not found error. I have also gone through the file names and upgraded them to 3.0.

Comment: Did u change the file names ?? First letter should be capitals. in controller and models

Comment: did u removed what i told in `config.php` file??

Comment: $config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';     these are my base url and index. in the config.php

Comment: yep. but now I can't access my home screen with the index.php taken out. It's very confusing!! Thank you for you patience

Comment: i have updated `.htaccess` code. please check and update the file and try once.